# Convertir variable de tipo float a decimal en Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
DECLARE @A FLOAT

SET @A = 26069175.1934196

SELECT @A

SELECT CAST (@A AS DECIMAL(6,2))
```

El resultado que busco es: 26069.19

Que son los primeros 6 enteros de izquierda a derecha y 2 decimales de la misma manera.

tengo el error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting float to data type numeric.

Comment: pues el requerimiento no es típico, y ciertamente no se puede hacer con una simple conversión de tipo de datos. (`decimal(6,2)` significa que el número tiene 6 dígitos en total, de los cuales 2 son para la parte decimal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que estás utilizando un decimal(6,2), o sea, un valor decimal de 6 dígitos, de los cuales 4 son para la parte entera y 2 para los decimales, pero 26069175.1934196 tiene más de 4 dígitos en su parte entera.

Creo que para resolver esto lo puedes hacer con un decimal (10,2), algo así:

```
DECLARE @A FLOAT

SET @A = 26069175.1934196

SELECT @A

SELECT CAST (@A AS DECIMAL(10,2))
```

¡Suerte!